# replace all commas except last one between two equal sign

Tags: unix, sed

I have a requirement that, I have a file and for each line I need to replace all commas `except the last one between two equal sign`. Can anyone help on this.

**(Prefer sed command and no looping condition)**

File's data-->>

```
STREET:1:1=Zwaneweg 23, Box 0001, PIN002,TOWN.COUNTRY:1:1=BE/Schilde
```

Should be-->>

```
STREET:1:1=Zwaneweg 23? Box 0001? PIN002,TOWN.COUNTRY:1:1=BE/Schilde
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The tag `unix` is strange, you may probably change it to a better one. If you are doing it in a linux/unix scripting language, you could tag the name of the scripting language. That being said, I would consider using a regular expression (AKA `regex`). Check them, try something yourself and edit your question to add a [mcve] of what you have tried and what is your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/Documents$ cat tt.txt
STREET:1:1=Zwaneweg 23, Box 0001, PIN002,TOWN.COUNTRY:1:1=BE/Schilde

mayankp@mayank:~/Documents$ cat tt.txt| grep -o -P '(?<==).*(?==)'| rev |sed 's/,/?/2g' |rev > out.txt
mayankp@mayank:~/Documents/$ cat out.txt
Zwaneweg 23? Box 0001? PIN002,TOWN.COUNTRY:1:1
```

Now merge `out.txt` with tt.txt to retain missed data.

```
mayankp@mayank:~/Documents/$ perl -0777 -i -pe "s/(=).*(=)/\$1`cat out.txt`\$2/s" tt.txt
mayankp@mayank:~/Documents$ cat t3.txt 
STREET:1:1=Zwaneweg 23? Box 0001? PIN002,TOWN.COUNTRY:1:1=BE/Schilde
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But Actually I dont want to replace last comma before equal sign. Means all comma should be replaced by question mark except last one which is before equal sign.

Comment: Thanks! Have checked your updated comment. It is working but it removes before and after equal to string. I dont want to remove any part of data.

Comment: In my file one line will be like this : 120186574|140201390//1,MNEMONIC:1:1=A140201390,STREET:1:1=Zwaneweg 23, Box 0001, PN474001,TOWN.COUNTRY:1:1=BE/Schilde,POST.CODE:1:1=2970

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you can remember matches and restore them.
When you only want to replace the second-last comma, you can use

```
sed -r 's/(=.*),(.*,.*=)/\1?\2/' inputfile
```

The wildcard is greedy, when you have 8 commas between the equal signs, the seventh will be replaced.
You can tell `sed` to repeat his instruction until it doesn't find a match witch a label. 
The label :a is inserted in front of the replace, and the "turnback" is instructed with `ta`. The command becomes

```
sed -r ':a;s/(=.*),(.*,.*=)/\1?\2/;ta' inputfile
```

When you have more than 2 equal sign, you must know where to look. This command will replace take the first ant last equal sign:

```
echo '1,a=2,b,b,b,=3,c=Only, this part, should have, the commas, except this one, replaced=5,e,e'|
   sed -r ':a;s/(=.*),(.*,.*=)/\1?\2/;ta'
1,a=2?b?b?b?=3?c=Only? this part? should have? the commas? except this one, replaced=5,e,e
```

When you only want the replacements done between the last 2 equal signs, you need to replace the wildcard `.` with everything except the equal sign `[^=]`, what will give an even harder to read command

```
echo '1,a=2,b,b,b,=3,c=Only, this part, should have, the commas, except this one, replaced=5,e,e'|
   sed -r ':a;s/(=[^=]*),([^=]*,[^=]*=)([^=]*)$/\1?\2\3/;ta'
1,a=2,b,b,b,=3,c=Only? this part? should have? the commas? except this one, replaced=5,e,e
```